# Solution rebuild fails using MSBuild in command line but Visual Studio rebuild works fine

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I'd like to rebuild my solution using MSBuild in command line. So far I'm using this command

`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe d:\WorkCopy\AppServer.sln /t:Rebuild`

But when I've changed or deleted a file the rebuild fails. I'm getting the following error code

`Ulohy\GetUlohy.cs(27,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace
name 'PocitacZaznamov' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or
 an assembly reference?)`

But when I use the Visual Studio rebuild command, solution builds fine. My guess I'm missing some paramater for MSBuild..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the solution saved before you do the command line build?

Sounds like the solution isn't updated, but when you do a rebuild in VS, it automatically saves the files before the build starts.